# Don't cut off question titles on the search result page

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, title

Feature request: Don't cut off question titles on the search result page. [Example](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=opt+ltc):

[image]

Comment: The truncation is being done server-side (i.e. the actual title text in the page ends with "…"), which isn't a reasonable way to do it, given that the display is supposed to be "responsive". If there's a desire to have the length limited, then that should be based on limiting the title text to one or N wrapped lines. If it's going to be truncated, then that should be done in CSS such that the truncation happens at the end of the line of text in the vertical space that's decided upon as the maximum to use for the title.

Comment: @Makyen Agreed, but for consistency purposes, I think that truncation should either be removed or applied to other pages like /questions and /questions/tagged. Currently, it seems to only be applied to /search.